# How can I select the current date

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have a DateTimePicker. By default it shows the current date. In order to select a date by means of the calendar, I have to click on a date and then to assign the DateTimePicker.Value to a variable in the DateTimePicker_ValueChanged event handler. When I select the current day, the DateTimePicker_ValueChanged event does not occur. How can I select the current date with the calendar? Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need a calendar to get the current date?

Comment: @user2102327 I have no control over the user's selection. I have though to enable the user to select also the current date if he so decides

Comment: @user2102327, There is something wrong in the way you are trying to achieve your goal, maybe you can tell what your scenariois , But as `DateTimePicker` default value is set to current time , clearly it would not call `ValueChanged` if u reselect this value , why not initialize the target time with `DateTime.Now`?

Comment: But what are you doing in the ValueChanged event handler? In other words. What is the code that depends on the date changing  event? Can you simply ignore this event and get the DateTimePicker.Value when you have finished with the form?(IE: OK click)

Comment: @user2102327 This is not an initialization. The DateTimePicker default time to show must be the current date. The user must select a date, which can be any date between DateTimePicker.MinDate and up to the current date inclusive.

Comment: @user2102327 This form is a specialized form whose sole purpose is to enable the user to select a date. I instantiate this form from a main form a number of times in order to get a range of dates from the user.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following facts:

- When you dropa `DateTimePicker` on form, no `Value` will be set for the control and the control just shows `DateTime.Now` by default, without raising `ValueChanged`.
- `ValueChanged` event will raise when a different `Value` explicitly is set for the `DateTimePicker` control.

So:

1. If you have not set a `Value` in constructor:

   - When the form loads, `ValueChanged` will not raise.
   - The first time the user choose today, `ValueChanged` will raise.
2. If you have set a `Value` in constructor:

   - When the form loads, `ValueChanged` will raise.
   - The first time the user choose today, `ValueChanged` will not raise, because there is no change in `Value`

### Example

Assuming you have a code like this:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(date.ToString());
}
```

You have some logic in `ValueChanged` event of `DateTimePicker` which is relying on `Value` of the `DateTimePicker` and you want that logic run when user selects a date, including Today. But your observation is, the first time which the form opens,`ValueChanged` doesn't raise.

The reason is you drop a `DateTimePicker` on form, no `Value` will be set for the control and the control just shows `DateTime.Now` by default, without raising `ValueChanged`.

**Option 1 - Set `DateTimePicker.Value` explicitly in constructor or Load**

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
}
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(date.ToString());
}
```

**Option 2 - Encapsulate the logic in a method and call it in constructor or Load**

You can encapsulate the logic in a method and call the method in constructor or load by passing `DateTime.Now`:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DoSomething(DateTime.Now);
}
void DoSomething(DateTime date)
{
    MessageBox.Show(date.ToString());
}
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething(dateTimePicker1.Value);
}
```

Comment: As I explained to the previous answer, the DateTimePicker default time to show must be the current date. The user must select a date, which can be any date between DateTimePicker.MinDate and up to the current date inclusive.

Comment: The post is answering the same question. Above answer selects the current date in constructor which raises `ValueChanged` as expected.

Comment: The date is not selected by me. The user must select a date and I have no control over the user's choice. The current date is an allowed date.

Comment: Did you give the code a try? It raises the `ValueChanged` event when your form load. It means your initial logic (by selecting DateTime.Now) will run.

Comment: "Reza Aghaei I cannot load the user's choice in the constructor as the user will make his selection at run time.

Comment: So you cannot expect your logic run on load. You should wait until the user selects something. Don't assign anything as value and this way, `ValueChange` will raise when user select any date, including today.

Comment: Read the first part of the answer carefully.

Comment: "Reza Aghaei The only logic in the dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged event handler is:private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    selectedDate = dateTimePicker1.Value; this.Close();
}                                                                                                                                                          The main form then reads this v\alue. #The sole purpose of this form is to elicit a date from the user.

Comment: Use option one if it's more meaningful for you. There is nothing more to add to the answer. In fact the first part of the post describes all you need to know to be able to describe and resolve the situation.